# Parse youtube ID from string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string as a PHP variable.

```
<div class="entry-content-asset">
     <div class="embed">
      <iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DSP_yxvRZOA?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to programatically search this string and find only the Video ID `DSP_yxvRZOA`

The string is the same every time save for the youtube video id.  I am terrible at writing regular expressions, can anyone save me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string is named `$str`:

```
$re = '/embed\/(.*)\?feature/';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Will match anything between `embed/` and `?feature` and put it into the first capturing group.